# Dell xps 9310 : installed ubuntu 20.04.2 as dual boot, grub shows up but has no entry for ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, xps

I installed ubuntu 20.04.2 as dual boot on a dell XPS 9310, which came installed with Windows 10 home.
Before doing this disabled secure boot in BIOS and changed disk from RAID to AHCI.
Disabled fastboot in windows and shrunk the C drive to create empty space for ubuntu installation.
After creating live ubuntu USB with rufus, installation happened without issues.

After reboot I get to grub but there are only two entries in there. First one for Windows and second for UEFI firmware settings. There is no entry for ubuntu, which usually should be the first entry.

Reinstalled 4 times with different options like 'install along windows' 'something else and creating partitions', nothing worked. Even wiping windows did not help. I always have only those two options in grub.

I have checked with the live USB that the root system is installed on the partition and all the folders are created with files.

EFI partition has boot and ubuntu folders created with the usual files.

Reinstalling grub via live USB did not help.

Is it a firmware problem.

Excuse me for the long post.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an OEM install bug on 20.04.02, which resulted in boot failure because of a missing kernel. It occurred while installing when connected to internet.
I managed to install it offline, which booted without problem and the Ubuntu being listed on the grub.
Canonical re-released Ubuntu 20.04.2 with the kernel included, removing the bug.